# Julia: sorting a matrix by 2 columns in different orders

Tags: sorting, matrix, julia

I need to sort a four column matrix in Julia by the third column in ascending order then by the fourth column in descending order.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do chained lexicographic sorting on columns in an arbitrary order is to pass a transformation `by` function: `sortrows(A, by=x->(x[3],x[4]))`… but that's just lexicographic with both columns ascending.  In order to do fancier behaviors, you can pass a custom comparison function to `sortrows`:

```
julia> A = rand(1:3,6,4)
6x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  1  1  2
 1  1  3  1
 1  1  2  1
 2  1  3  3
 1  3  3  1
 2  3  2  3

julia> sortrows(A, lt=(x,y)->isless(x[3],y[3]) || (isequal(x[3],y[3]) && isless(y[4],x[4])))
6x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  1  1  2
 2  3  2  3
 1  1  2  1
 2  1  3  3
 1  1  3  1
 1  3  3  1
```

Comment: using the same `by` argument, `by=x->(x[3],-x[4])` will do the descending order for the fourth column (note the minus sign).